# Compute $\int_{\Gamma} z^{-2} dz$ where $\Gamma=C_1(0)$ with its usual (counterclockwise) parametrization.

Tags: complex-analysis

Compute $\int_{\Gamma} z^{-2} dz$ where $\Gamma=C_1(0)$ with its usual (counterclockwise) parametrization.

I calculated the integral manually, but I want a little practice with the following theorem (which I'm assuming is applicable since it's in the same section as the problem in the book):

> Let $f(z)$ be continuous in a domain $\Omega$ and suppose $F(z)$ is a function defined, analytic, and satisfying $F^{\prime}(z)=f(z)$ at all points $z \in \Omega$. If $\Gamma$ is a curve in $\Omega$ from $z_0$ to $z_1$, then $$\int_{\Gamma} f(z) dz = \int_{\Gamma} F^{\prime}(z) dz = F(z_1)-F(z_0).$$

We have $F(z)= -z^{-1}$ and $F^{\prime}(z)=z^{-2}$. I tried proving that $F(z)$ is analytic, but it seems like it doesn't satisfy the Cauchy Riemann equations since the partial derivatives I calculated don't satisfy $u_y=-v_x$. I double checked my partial derivatives with Wolfram Alpha and they were the same. Was I just sloppy with the computing partial derivatives, or is this theorem not applicable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the definition of line integral directly. Let $z=e^{i\theta}\;(0\le \theta\le 2\pi)$, then
$$
\int_\Gamma \frac{dz}{z^2}=\int_0^{2\pi} ie^{-i\theta}d\theta=0.
$$
In general, you can derive
$$
\int_\Gamma z^n dz =\begin{cases}
0,&n\ne -1\\
2\pi i,&n=-1
\end{cases}
$$
for integer $n$.

Comment: You don't need the existence of an anti-derivative everywhere inside $\Gamma$.

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly fine to use the complex version of the fundamental theorem of calculus here. You only need the existence of an anti-derivative on (an open neighborhood of) the curve $\Gamma$.

In your case, the anti-derivative exists on, for example, $\Omega = \{ \frac12 < |z| < 2 \}$, so the integral over the closed curve $\Gamma$ is indeed $0$.